# How to create a cocoa touch framework from a code that depends on 3rd party libraries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a cocoa touch framework out of my existing app so it can be embedded in other apps via a simple drag and drop.

The thing is my app uses a lot of libraries and have been using cocoapods to manage dependencies.

I already know how to build a simple framework but I couldn't find a source that talked about how to turn a complex project with lots of dependency into a framework.

Questions:

1. Is it even possible to achieve my goal (Package my own code and all the libraries it depends on into a single framework that can be easily embedded into other projects)
2. if yes what's the right way to do it?
3. Assuming all of the above were resolved, what happens when the parent app also contains some of the same libraries that are being used in my framework?